# Build events: copy file with elevated rights

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I need a command that I can use in Visual Studio's Post-build event command line that can copy a file using **elevated** rights.

- `runas` is not an option as my user can elevate privileges.
- starting VS as admin is also not an option.

What is the best way?

For the sake of completeness: I want to install CustomComponents for SSIS automatically on my development machine.

Comment: create a scheduled task that runs with elevated rights and [run it via Post-build event with schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "taskname"](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to start a powershell with elevated privileges.
In this powershell a `gacutil` und `copy` are used to install the CustomComponents locally.

The command I use in VS2015 with SQLServer 2017 is:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList('/K', 'copy /Y \"$(TargetPath)\" \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\PipelineComponents\" && \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe\" /i \"$(TargetPath)\" /f')" -Verb RunAs
```